# 3D Surface of a pyramid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I'm trying to plot an irregular frustum and then a question occurred to me: is it possible to represent the coordinate $z$ as a function of the cartesian coordinates $x,y$ for a pyramid face in order to create a surface? (Like a triangle in 3D space, but not necessarily parallel to any axis)

It may sound like a simple question but I could find nothing similar. Sorry if it is trivial, and thank you in advance!

Comment: you can find the cartesian equation of each plane surface separately if you have enough information, such as the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Yes, suppose i have a triangle in 3D space that I know the points of the vertices, how do I find the plane equation?

Comment: Do you know about cross-product of vectors? If not, perhaps it would help to read up on that. Oh, you're a structural engineer; you must know this from physics. You get the normal vector to the plane by taking the cross-product of vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$, where $ABC$ is your triangle.